# Create a react app using a script in JAVA

Tags: java, reactjs, npm, processbuilder

so my purpose is to develop a script in java, once I execute it, it will generate a react app with its structure! 
How to run the command `npm create-react-app` in JAVA code, shall I use `ProcessBuilder` API or something else! I need your help

Comment: this might answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40503074/how-to-run-npm-command-in-java-using-process-builder

Comment: use maven?
for example:
https://medium.com/@itzgeoff/including-react-in-your-spring-boot-maven-build-ae3b8f8826e